# asp isobject check and timeout

Tags: asp-classic, session-timeout

i have this skratch of code that manage the user session:

```
if IsObject(Session("operator")) then
  Set operator = Session("operator")
  operatore_id = operator.Item("id")
else
  response.redirect "controller.asp"
end if
```

before this i have set the Session.Timeout = 30, but after about a couple of minutes, the user get redirected to "controller.asp" as if the session("operator") isn't prsent anymore.
any advice to prevent this? i would like to let users remain "logged" as much as possble, becouse most times they have to write lot of text and most of the time they get redirected when they try to save the work.

any advice?

Comment: I can't explain why your session expires before the timeout, but it's best practice to keep objects out of sessions. A better way to implement this is by storing the data you need in a database and storing the ID of the operator-record in a cookie. You can expire te cookie whenever you want (for example when the user closes their browser).

Comment: this is the last chance, due to the fact that i haven't make the application and changing the way it does the login is a long work. i understand that this is the right choice infact i usually implement things like that. thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using an iframe  of 0px that calls a page that contains the code:

```
<%
Response.AddHeader "Refresh", "50"
%>
```

It is a bit rude, but it works.